# How do I turn off CTRL+M hotkey?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I have a game where it is required to press CTRL+M simultanously and it does not work, because it behaves like the "ENTER"-button.
That game does not allow me to use anything like AutoHotkey or something to remap or deactivate that hotkey for a certain time.

Still how can I fix it? I was looking up Google but nothing helpful, only got results on how to disable Win-Key + Something.

Any idea on how to do this? I am using right control + M.

Thanks for any incoming help!

Comment: Control M is "mark mode" in command prompt.

Comment: I don't have windows 10 here so I can't verify, but maybe http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/disable-or-enable-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-cmd-on-windows-10.html

Comment: Well, still doesn't fix my problem...If I press ctrl+m in editor, it behaves like enter key. I tried your solution already, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Any function keys enabled on the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this question, as it helped me finding a solution to a very similar problem. Hope my findings can assist you in tracing down yours'.

At first, it helps, sorting things:

CTRL-M is an Application Specific Key, so in general any application which captures the keyboard is free to assign any meaning / behavour to it. Presumably your game has done exactly this. In general, for a key mapping to take effect, the application needs focus. Normally either the App is the focussed window, or has focus in full screen mode. (If this was the entire story you wouldn't have a problem.)

Unfortunately Windows has component(s) which have or provide (sort of) "global" focus. At least the Sys tray and the Task bar (both part of the Windows Explorer/Shell, I think) have this capeability. Windows itself registers globally a couple of "WinKey + [x]" hotkeys and a few others (e.g. CTRL + ESC or ALT + TAB) but not CTRL + M. You can check Windows (claimed) Key mappings here: [Keyboard Shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10). (Windows/Microsoft Apps use CTRL + M only when having focus.)

This leaves 2 possabilities for your behavior:

1. The (wrong) mapping in your game comes from your game - either a bug or a malconfiguration you're not aware of, or
2. An other application has registered the CTRL + M hotkey globally, presumably during installation with admin privileges.

Example for (2.): MobaXterm (MX) registers CTRL + M globally with "Send MX to .../Restore MX from Systray." which had very annoying effects for any application that tried to use CTRL + M in a nice, focussed manner. If this is the situation, you're dealing with, you have to find out, which application it is and deactivate the mapping there. Maybe [Defkey: Applications using CTRL + M](https://defkey.com/what-means/ctrl-m) can help you in this search.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to avoid this is just remapping the key in game to something else.
Ctrl + M will always be enter in let's say notepad.

Comment: I can't remap the key ingame. :/